# How to show back and forward button on popup opened thru window.open or self.open for Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

i am opening the popup window with below code snippet

```
   self.open('myJSPPage','ServicePopUp','height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes');
```

Once the window opens i do not see any back button or forward button on popup. I just see title then address bar under it and then myJSPPage under address bar.
I am not getting how to show back and forward button on popup?

**Edit:-** i am using google crome. Looks like above code working on IE

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? That code works well enough for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: For an awe inspiring use of `window.open`, view this **HTML5 Chrome** only [**DEMO**](http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/). This doesn't address you question, but shows the power of `window.open`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tested this example and it gives me forward and back button on FF
[try this](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_popup_window_code.cfm)

```
<!-- Codes by Quackit.com -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.quackit.com/html/html_help.cfm');">Open a popup window</a>
```

jsfiddle live demo for your code an mine it gave me buttons on FF test

**update:**
yes you are right chrome does not give the result expected

possible duplicate

[another asked question in stack over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568064/how-to-window-open-with-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome)
    Unfortunately Chrome only supports a small set of window features when using window.open. If you believe that this is a bug or an issue you can file it at http://crbug.com.

If you just use window.open(url) then it will open a new tab in the same window with the buttons you desire.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/wfgPR/)

Comment: Looks like my code and the code provided works everywhere except chrome?

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome only supports a small set of window features when using window.open. If you believe that this is a bug or an issue you can file it at http://crbug.com.

Comment: Back button on IE is not consistent when its visible. On one example is shows on the other it does not. same code