# enable user to return previous page in new window

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have PHP form where user can insert a movie name in the textbox, then by clicking a button "search", a new window is opened showing list of movies contain the word that user has inserted in the textbox.

For example the image below shows list of movies contain the word "froz":

[image]

Now, if user click on any of movie names in the new window (for example "Frozen"), this page will be shown:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, the window does not have the back in the browser. My question is how can I enable user to return to the previous page (the page which shows list of movies)?

This is the code when user click on "search" button which opens a new window (showing list of movies):

```
$('#btnSearch').on('click', function (e) {           
           window.textbox = $('#q').val();
           window.searchType = $('input:radio[name=source]:checked').val();

           popupCenter("movielist.php","_blank","400","400");
  });
```

and this is the code where I defined the url for when user click on movie name.

```
 <td><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/<?php echo urlencode($row['ImdbId']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>
```

All ideas are highly appreciated,

Comment: Opening windows is almost never a good idea. Try using new tab instead of a new window, or some kind of javascript modal window.

Comment: I guess `popupCenter` opens a new window? try to open your link in the same window instead

Comment: @ItayGal: I think I cannot do it, because it's just for one of the questions in my php form.. there are some other question in the same page.. I don't know if it's good to open the link in the same window or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use options like toolbar=yes,menubar=yes when you open a new popup window.

Related question: [Show Back/Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990494/how-to-show-back-and-forward-button-on-popup-opened-thru-window-open-or-self-ope)