# window.open doesn't open with browser back button in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, window.open

I am trying to open a link in new window using a simple `window.open`.

However I want the browser back button, so I give the below parameters. It works fine in all browsers except Google Chrome. I have tried almost every possible permutation but the back button doesn't come up in Chrome:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com',
                        'popUpWindow',
                        'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=yes,directories=no, status=yes'
                       );">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: did you check popup blockers?

Comment: When you click on the link, It opens a new window. So while clicking back button, where do you expect the page to go ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568064/how-to-window-open-with-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome

Comment: It opens a new window, So it is a fresh page, so there is no previous page, Back button doesn't make any sense here, am I correct ?

Comment: +1 for your question :)

Comment: I dont want it to redirect anywhere. Just want the popup window look same as the browser with the browser back button

Comment: @mr.VVoo: yes,i have checked that.. wouldn't popup blocker disable the popup window itself??.. am able to get the popup window but without the disabled navigation(back and forward) buttons

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568064/how-to-window-open-with-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Change `menubar=no` to `menubar=yes`, here is the code.

**NOTE** : It will not open as pop up, it will open as a new tab.

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com',
                        'popUpWindow',
                        'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,directories=no, status=yes'
                       );">Click Here</a>
```