# Edittable URL Pop Up Windows

Tags: javascript, html, popup

How do you open a tabless popup for users that allows users to still edit the address bar?

**Goal:** We are trying to create small tabless pop up windows so the user can drag them on top of their current applications while working.  But they sometimes need the ability to change their url slightly.

For example if you have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<div id=test>open</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function(){
    window.open("http://stackoverflow.com", "_blank", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=300, height=300, top=10, left=10");
}
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/axomid/1/

[image: pic]

So how do you allow the user to successfully edit the url bar.

For example I would like the user to be able to change stackoverflow.com to stackexchange.com.

Comment: Might be applicable http://stackoverflow.com/q/2568064

Comment: You might consider JavaScript-based popup windows that host an iframe. You can add your own fake address bar. May be a bit of work though.

Comment: @Mark interesting idea would that work cross domain?

Comment: Yes, you can host whatever URL you want in your iframe, but you won't be able to access its contents. I don't know if you're able to monitor the iframe URL changing though, such as when they click a link in the iframe.

Comment: Nevermind, I don't think it's possible Same-domain policy gets in the way too much. http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/NwmZc/