# opening a new window through javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

I need open a new window/popup with toolbar enabled.

I have this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pnb7y/13/

That has this code:

```
window.open(this.href,"popupwindow", "width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=yes,resizable");
```

Toolbar is displayed well only in firefox, but not in chrome or ie

Do you know anyway to display toolbar in chrome?

NOTE: another thing I'd like is to hide the address...but I've read that this isn't possible due to security reasons...but if you know a way, I want to know.

Best regards, Daniel

Comment: Unfortunately, chrome just doesn't support it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568064/how-to-window-open-with-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome

Comment: Could I open a new window with another instruction???

Answer (score 0):

```
function pollwin(url,w, h)
{
pollwindow=window.open(url,'pollwindow','top=0,left=0,status=no,toolbars=no,scrollbars=no,width='+w+',height='+h+',maximize=no,resizable');
pollwindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: Does it work in google chrome?? do you see the new window with toolbar?? can you select back arrow button in order to back ?

Comment: I have tested in chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: I'm using Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: Danial: I have tested focus not toolbar,and yes toolbar not working here

Comment: Thank you dear, but I'm interested on toolbar...I'd like that it displays itself well

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(this.href,"popupwindow",   "width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=yes,resizable");
```

Use this

```
window.open(this.href,"popupwindow", "width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=yes,resizable",target="_blank");
```