# Chrome Browser's window.open

Tags: javascript, html, browser

when I open a new window use the window.open function in chrome browser,the new window has no back button no matter what the parameters are.
Code like this below:

```
window.open(url,'newwindow','toolbar=yes, menubar=yes, location=yes, status=yes...');
```

Any helps will be gratefull!

Comment: That's because it's a popup, not an actual browser window. It's the browser's choice as to whether it opens a new tab/window or popup.

Comment: @mattytommo — Popups *are* actual browser windows. This has nothing to do with opening in new tabs.

Comment: may be you can try window.open(url, '_blank');

Comment: already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568064/how-to-window-open-with-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

May be it will solve your problem

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

The new window won't have a history. Maybe you could hack something together with the HTML5 History API and Cookies:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: That would cause the back button to be greyed out, not to be non-existent.

Comment: How do you mean? What i'm suggesting is creating a fake history that could be retrieved via a cookie and created with the history api. This is only a theory atm.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it because you can't have control on the manner Chrome opens its windows.
It opens a new window, So it is a fresh page, so there is no previous page, Back button doesn't make any sense here, am I correct ?

Comment: No. If there isn't a history, then there can still be a back button. It is just greyed out. The question is about the toolbar that includes the back button not appearing at all.

Comment: There are some restriction or we can say chrome does not support back/forward button  for pop up window.So it can be done by window.open(url) which  will open a new tab in the same window