# It is possible to open new window with navigation bar and tabs?

Tags: javascript, function, browser, window.open, specs

I try to open a new window in js with this function
`window.open("myurl", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes");`

It's work, myurl is in a new window but the nav arrows and the tabs bar are not displayed

Is is a restriction of browsers ?
Anyone have a solution ?

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to window.open with a toolbar in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568064/how-to-window-open-with-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome)

Comment: It's (to the extent of my knowledge) only possible to open a link in a new tab or a popup window. Opening it in a full-featured browser window is not possible.

Comment: @davethebrave Thanks but it's an old post and this bug is not fixed , i tried to find a other solution for my problem

Comment: @Pete I don't know , this solution display the nav bar and tabs ?

Comment: @Pete Ok thanks but i use js like this in my back java with jsf and primefaces :  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(
          "window.open(url, '_blank', 'toolbar=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes')");

Comment: @knosmos Thanks for your answer ! Ok so bad :'(